# ERROR StatusLogger No logging configuration

Tags: log4j2

I am using log4j2

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

and a very basic configuration xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration PUBLIC "-//APACHE//DTD LOG4J 1.2//EN" "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%t] %C{2} (%F:%L) - %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <category name="org.apache.log4j.xml">
        <priority value="info" />
    </category>
    <Root>
        <priority value ="debug" />
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </Root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

For some reason logging is not working. I am getting

```
ERROR StatusLogger Error parsing /home/sfalk/workspace/java/lazy-model-access/lamoa-parent/lamoa-server/target/classes/log4j2.xml
ERROR StatusLogger No logging configuration
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your configuration file is for log4j 1.x, not 2.5